# linq : find values in list exist in another list or not?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a small problem, from the below code first we are finding hostelStops with ID, hostelName, InTime
then we are taking wardenkduty with DutyName, tasksStart

now, I want to check whether hostelStops-hostelName is exist in taskList-taskStart

```cs
var hostelStops = 
    (from item in Hostel.Where(tn => tn.HostelNumber == hostelNumber).SelectMany(x => x.Hostels)
    select new
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        hostelName = hostelName.Single(p => p.Id == item.hostelId).SymbolicName,
        InTime = item.InTimeTime                                 
    }).ToList();

var taskList = 
    (from row in filteredWardenDuty
    select new
    {
        dutyName = row.DutyName,
        taskStart = row.WardenTasks.Select(x => x.Context.Start.PlaceId)
    }).ToList();
```

so, i have written below code

```cs
var isExist = 
    from row in taskList
    select new
    {
        task = row.taskStart.Contains((from item in hostelStops select item.hostelName ))
    };
```

but, receiving error as

> Error CS1929  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<IEnumerable>(ReadOnlySpan<IEnumerable>, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'ReadOnlySpan<IEnumerable>'

Comment: could you please edit your question regarding code snippets. It's not quite readable. Maybe you miss `using System.Linq;` ...?

Comment: thanks for the response but System.Linq is exist at the top of class file

Comment: are you sure, you have a list named `stops`? shouldn't it be `hostelStops `?

Comment: actually in taskList, hostelStops values are present but, while design time itself we got this error

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `someCollection.Contains(otherCollection)`, you have to do `someCollection.Any(item => otherCollection.Contains(item))` (in english: "is any item from this collection contained in that collection") so something like:

```
row.taskStart.Any(ts => (from item in hostelStops select item.hostelName).Contains(ts));
```

It would perhaps be more performant to make your hostelstops into a hashset:

```
var hs = (from item in hostelStops select item.hostelName).ToHashSet();
...
row.taskStart.Any(ts => hs.Contains(ts));
```

You haven't been clear about what types these are; this will only work if the two collections are of the same basic type (like string) or a type that is able to be compared properly even if theyre different instances, for which you may have to write a custom comparer or an Equals/GetHashcode pair of overrides